# Retrieve and update the NoteTags from Onenote page

Tags: office-addins, onenote-api

I created an Office Add-In for Onenote and I am trying to retrieve and update the NoteTags properties on the page.

The image shows the Onenote page with 4 ToDo tags. It also shows the console log resulting from the code below. In the console I can see the paragrah id, type, and text from the ToDo tags.

What do I need to change in the code to retrieve the 'Id', 'Status' and 'Type' of the NoteTags and how can I clear the ToDo tags that are checked?

[Onenote page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdCWS.png)

```
function getParagraph() {
    OneNote.run(function (context) {

        // Get the collection of pageContent items from the page.
        var pageContents = context.application.getActivePage().contents;
    
        // Get the first PageContent on the page, and then get its Outline's first paragraph.
        var pageContent = pageContents.getItemAt(0);
        var paragraphs = pageContent.outline.paragraphs;

        paragraphs.load("id, type, richText");
    
        // Run the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                // Display the properties.
                $.each(paragraphs.items, function(index, paragraph) {
                    // Write text from paragraph to console
                    console.log(
                        "Paragraph Id: " + paragraph.id +
                        "; Type: " + paragraph.type + 
                        "; Text: " + paragraph.richText.text);
                });
            });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        onError(error);
    });   
}
```